# How do I add IAM Role to S3 Bucket Policy in Serverless Framework CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-s3, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, serverless-framework

I am using Serverless Framework and creating a stack with additional S3 Buckets one of which needs to have a bucket policy that needs the IamRoleLambdaExecution role created in Serveless Framework added to the Principal section of that bucket's policy; how do I go about doing that?

The bucket policy in the stack as is:

```
    S3BucketManifestPolicy:
      Type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy'
      Properties:
        Bucket: my-quicksight-manifest
        PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
            - Action:
                - 's3:*'
              Effect: Allow
              Resource:
                - !Join ['', ['arn:aws:s3:::', !Ref 'mymanifestqs', /*]]
              Principal: 
                AWS: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:user/serverless-admin
                Service:
                - s3.amazonaws.com
                - cloudformation.amazonaws.com
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
                - quicksight.amazonaws.com
```

In the principal section I already have the serverless-admin user and some services, but wasn't clear how to add this particular resource to that section which isn't explicitly created in the stack but seems to be part of the Serverless Framework features when a stack is deployed. [Reference to IamRoleLambdaExecution here](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/resources/)

I'm a bit new to CloudFormation in general, and I think I added those additional items correctly in the Principal section, but I could be wrong there too.

Any input on how to correctly reference IamRoleLambdaExecution Role into that principal section, or any other advice, would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

**Edit**

I think I found what I was looking for, and made the changes to the Principal Section. I'm unfortunately still experiencing issues with stack and access control, but it seems to be unrelated to this particular syntax. The updated stack is now this:

```
    S3BucketManifestPolicy:
      Type: 'AWS::S3::BucketPolicy'
      Properties:
        Bucket: profico-quicksight-manifest
        PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
            - Action:
                - 's3:*'
              Effect: Allow
              Resource:
                - !Join ['', ['arn:aws:s3:::', !Ref 'proficiomanifestqs', /*]]
              Principal: 
                AWS: 
                  - 'arn:aws:iam::877539445438:user/serverless-admin'
                  - Fn::GetAtt: [ IamRoleLambdaExecution, Arn ] <-added here
                Service:
                  - s3.amazonaws.com
                  - cloudformation.amazonaws.com
                  - lambda.amazonaws.com
                  - quicksight.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: I couldn't understand your problem. Please let me know what are the resources that are created by Serverless and why you are trying to add the Lambda execution role to S3 bucket policy @SkyB

Comment: Hey there, thanks. I think I am on my way to the solution. I wanted to explicitly add that IamRoleLambdaExecution into the bucket Policy of one of my buckets, but was unsure how to do that. BUT, I think I was able to successfully accomplish that (see edit and updated bucket policy).